# Raspberry pi. Using two servos or ESC in perl with WiringPi::API

Tags: perl, raspberry-pi, gpio

im trying using two ESC or servos in WiringPi::API (perl). 1 servo works ok, when using 2 servos, it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
use WiringPi::API qw(:all);
use RPi::Const qw(:all);

setup_gpio();

pin_mode(ESC1_PIN, PWM_OUT);
pin_mode(ESC2_PIN, PWM_OUT);

pwm_set_mode(PWM_MODE_MS);
pwm_set_clock(NEUTRAL);
pwm_set_range(RANGE);

pwm_write(ESC1_PIN, 176);
pwm_write(ESC2_PIN, 176);
```

Thanks for help and reply.

Comment: Can you please link to the servos you're using? (Disclaimer: I'm the author of `WiringPi::API`)

Comment: Some of those constants do not exist in my software. Please add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` to your script.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's working now. The problem was the connection to bad pins not supporting PWM. I have one more question, can I use software pwm in WiringPI :: API (I want to connect multiple servos)? if not what is the alternative in perl?

Comment: I have a question about the communication between modules nrf24l01 via SPI? can i do it in wiringpi?

Comment: You can use the NRF24L01 using WiringPi::API, but you'll have to write your own SPI driver for it.